# Authorize.Net: What data do they send back to merchants to settle orders?

Tags: woocommerce, authorize.net

Trying to develop an app that connects to authorize.net but not sure about how the data is exchanged. What data does authorize.net send back to the merchant that they use to settle the order? What is this data called and where is it stored? Anyone know? It's for a WooCommerce app.

Answer (score 2):

Authorize.Net does not send any kind of notifications when an order is settled. They *do* send a notification when an order is processed (via [Silent Post](https://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/) or [webhooks](https://www.johnconde.net/blog/handling-authorize-net-webhooks-with-php/)*) and do give a response when the payment is processed, but no event is triggered when a settlement occurs.

If you want to know more information about a transaction after is has been processed you can call the Authorize.Net [Transaction Reporting API](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/transaction_reporting.html) for that data. Typically this occurs after a webhook notification but if the transaction needs to be settled first, you can wait until the transactions has settled (I believe this is after 3am EDT) to confirm the payment has settled.

If you are looking for an immediate response, Authorize.Net does give a lot of data back when a payment is made. Here is what an example response looks like (assuming you are using JSON and not XML):

```
{
   "transactionResponse":{
      "responseCode":"1",
      "authCode":"QWX20S",
      "avsResultCode":"Y",
      "cvvResultCode":"P",
      "cavvResultCode":"2",
      "transId":"2228446239",
      "refTransID":"",
      "transHash":"56B2D50D73CAB8C6EDE7A92B9BB235BD",
      "testRequest":"0",
      "accountNumber":"XXXX1111",
      "accountType":"Visa",
      "messages":[
         {
            "code":"1",
            "description":"This transaction has been approved."
         }
      ],
      "userFields":[
         {
            "name":"favorite_color",
            "value":"blue"
         }
      ]
   },
   "refId":"94564789",
   "messages":{
      "resultCode":"Ok",
      "message":[
         {
            "code":"I00001",
            "text":"Successful."
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This is the same information that is made available via Silent Post and webhooks mentioned above.

**I am the author of those articles*